# Check if a string is an int, long, float, boolean or double

Tags: scala

I want to check if a string is an int, long, float, double or boolean.

For example, "1" should be int, "1.22" should be float and "1.5555555" should be double.

This is the best I've managed:

```
case item: String =>

        if (item.toInt.toString.equals(item)) {
          arrayType = Int.getClass
          ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * array.length)
        }
        else if (item.toLong.toString.equals(item)) {
          arrayType = Long.getClass
          ByteBuffer.allocate(8 * array.length)
        }
        else if (item.toFloat.toString.equals(item)) {
          arrayType = Float.getClass
          ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * array.length)
        }
        else if (item.toDouble.toString.equals(item)) {
          arrayType = Double.getClass
          ByteBuffer.allocate(8 * array.length)
        }
        else if (item.toBoolean.toString.equals(item)) {
          arrayType = Boolean.getClass
          ByteBuffer.allocate(array.length)
        }

        else throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Type not supported: " + item.getClass)
```

Comment: This won't work because `toXXX` will throw exception if it cannot parse. You do need to test all cases, using `Try` to enclose the exception in a monad, something like `Try(item.toInt).map { _ => ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * array.length) }`

Comment: Note that `1.22` does not actually fit into a `Float` (or indeed into a `Double`), so you need to be more precise about what the different categories are.

Comment: can a string be `"true"`? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer will work, although it doesn't capture all cases. For example, digits suffixed by `f` or `d` can parse into a Double or a Float, as will certain strings like "Infinity" or "-Infinity". As an example, `"12.1234567893901f".toFloat -> 12.123457` and `"NaN".toFloat -> NaN`. Scientific or ["E" notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation) also parses into Floats/Doubles (becoming `±Infinity` if needed).

- `item.getClass` will always be `String` in the line above, so the "Type not supported" error message may be misleading, and you may prefer a `IllegalArgumentException` with a message that reveals `item` instead of `item.getClass`.
- Checking `s.toXXX.toString.equals(s)` won't work for values of `s` which can successfully parse but are "unsimplified". One case is a long string of digits: `"61234817390131412313458".toDouble.toString = "6.123481739013142E22"`. The same is true of other "unsimplified" values, e.g. `"+0".toFloat.toString = "0.0"`
- As mentioned in comments and previous answers, each `toXXX` method can throw an error, so to try all of them, they can be wrapped in a `Try`. The `find` method of a `List` will stop on and return the first element that produces `isSuccess` being `true`.
- If `s.toFloat` doesn't throw an error, then `s.toDouble` won't throw an error, and vice versa. Both should succeed or fail together. Therefore, further checks need to be done to see which one is more suitable (but `toString.equals` is probably too specific as mentioned).

  - Certain (either very positive or negative) values become `±Infinity` when parsed into a float but not double. If an input is forced into `Infinity` for float but not `Double`, then you might prefer a `Double`. If the input parses to `Infinity` for both types, then choose either type.
  - Inputs too small will be forced to zero sooner for `Float` than for `Double`.

Here's an outline of possible function definitions:

```
object t {
  type Result = (Int, Class[_])
  type ListElt = (Result, String => Any)
  def useFloat(s:String): Boolean = {
    // determine if choosing Float is "desirable"
    val floatVal:Float = s.toFloat
    val doubleVal:Double = s.toDouble
    // if very little precision is lost, or if the maximum information stored isn't lost completely
    val MAX_LOST:Double = 1E-5.min(doubleVal)
    val preservedPrecision:Boolean = (floatVal - doubleVal).abs <= MAX_LOST
    // Remove this variable if `Double` is preferred when bothInfinite
    val bothInfinite:Boolean = floatVal.isInfinite && doubleVal.isInfinite
    preservedPrecision || bothInfinite
  }
  def getSizeAndType(s: String): Option[Result] = {
    val floatResult:Result = (4, Float.getClass)
    val doubleResult:Result = (8, Double.getClass)
    val conversions: List[ListElt] = List(
      ((4, Int.getClass), ((x: String) => x.toInt)),
      ((8, Long.getClass), ((x: String) => x.toLong)),
      (floatResult, ((x: String) => x.toFloat)),
      (doubleResult, ((x: String) => x.toDouble)),
      ((1, Boolean.getClass), ((x: String) => x.toBoolean))
    )
    val firstSuccess: Option[ListElt] = conversions.find((elt: ListElt) => scala.util.Try(elt._2(s)).isSuccess)
    val result = firstSuccess.map(_._1)
    // check if choosing Float is "desirable"
    result match {
      case Some(`floatResult`) =>
        if (useFloat(s)){
          Some(floatResult)
        } else {
          Some(doubleResult)
        }
      case other => other
    }
  }
  def handle(s:String) = {
    val (bytes, arrayType) = getSizeAndType(s).getOrElse(0, "None")
    if (bytes > 0) {
      // perform allocation
      //ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * array.length)
      println(s"${bytes}, ${arrayType}")
    } else {
      // throw exception, etc.
      println("Not parsable")
    }
  }
}

println(t.handle("9")) // 4, class scala.Int$
println(t.handle("1.9")) // 4, class scala.Float$
println(t.handle("2147483648")) // 8, class scala.Long$
println(t.handle("2.5769803776E9")) // 8, class scala.Double$ (small enough for finite float but loses enough precision)
println(t.handle("3.4028235E38")) // 8, class scala.Double$ (ditto)
println(t.handle("6.805647E38")) // 8, class scala.Double$ (too big for finite float)
println(t.handle("12.123456789")) // 4, class scala.Float$
println(t.handle("Infinity")) // 4, class scala.Float$
println(t.handle("false")) // 1, class scala.Boolean$
println(t.handle("xyz")) // Not parsable
```

Comment: Very impressive!

Answer (score 5):

I don't see how the posted code can work. If `item` is `"true"` then `.toInt` will throw and never get to the `.toBoolean` test.

I'd be tempted to use RegEx to do the initial segregation and let `BigDecimal` do the number parsing.

```
val isBool = "(?i)(?:true|false)".r
val isNum = raw"\d*\.?\d+".r

item match {
  case isBool() => ...
  case isNum() =>
    val bd = BigDecimal(item)
    if      (bd.isValidInt)      ...
    else if (bd.isValidLong)     ...
    else if (bd.isDecimalFloat)  ...
    else if (bd.isDecimalDouble) ...
    else //too big to fit?
  case _ => //report bad item
}
```